# Javascript function is not returning the expected value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run the following function

```
var getjson = function(){
    $.get('/api/todos/testing', function(results){
        return results;
    });
}
```

The results should look like this:

```
[{_id: "57803baf0a76d5c924b18ca2", username: "testing", toDoTask: "Buy Water", isDone: false, __v: 0},{_id: "57803baf0a76d5c924b18ca3", username: "testing", toDoTask: "Buy Milk", isDone: false, __v: 0}]
```

When I try to call the function to append the list to my Angular controller

```
angular.module('firstapp').controller('todos', function(){
   this.list= getjson();
});
```

The list does not save the values returned by the function.

I'm sure the problem is related to the way I'm trying to return the results but I couldn't find what's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` is asynchronous so when you ran `getjson()`, the code will still do the `GET` operation but it will return straight away.

Since you did not define a `return` statement for it, by default javascript will give you back `undefined` which is what `this.list` will be set as.

Documentation for `$.get`: 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

To fix your problem the easiest way would be to make `getjson()` accept a callback function.

**Example:**

```
var getjson = function(done){
    $.get('/api/todos/testing', function(results){
        return done(results);
    });
}
```

Then you will call `getjson()` with a function that sets the `list`.

```
angular.module('firstapp').controller('todos', function(){
   getjson(function(results) { this.list = results; }));
});
```

Comment: Doesn't it return a promise?  If so, this answer might be more helpful if it showed how to pass a resolution function to the promise.